# Range at one order-of-magnitude in Python

Tags: python

I want to print `x` at one order-of-magnitude. However, there is an error. The desired output is attached.

```py
for x in range(0,1e-3):
    print(x)
```

The error is:

```
<module>
    for x in range(0,1e-3):

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The desired output is:

```
0
1e-6
1e-5
1e-4
1e-3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` to generate the powers of 10, and then you can use `itertools.chain()` to add the zero in front:

```py
from itertools import chain

for x in chain([0], map(lambda x: 10**x, range(-7, -2))):
    print(x)
```

This outputs:

```py
0
1e-07
1e-06
1e-05
0.0001
0.001
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(10**(i-7) if i else 0)
```

output:

```
0
1e-06
1e-05
0.0001
0.001
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a range from a float. i.e 1e-3 = 0.001. What will be the iterations between 0-0.001?
You can run from 6-0 i.e range(6,0,-1) and print(10**(-i))

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want the range to be logarithmic
I would say do something like:

```
for exponent in range(-7, -2):
    print(10**exponent)
```

Comment: You will have to add a `print(0)` at the start to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Tossing my hat in the ring, in case you want to keep the scientific notation formatting:

```py
for i in range(-7, -2):
    print(f"{round(10**i, 6):.1e}")
```

Output:

```py
0.0e+00
1.0e-06
1.0e-05
1.0e-04
1.0e-03
```

Or, using `.1E`:

```py
0.0E+00
1.0E-06
1.0E-05
1.0E-04
1.0E-03
```

You can also generalize:

```py
def orders_of_magnitude(lo, hi):
    return [round(10**i, abs(lo) - 1) for i in range(lo, hi)]
```

Demo:

```py
In [2]: for x in orders_of_magnitude(-12, -0):
   ...:     print(f"{x:.0e}")
   ...:
0e+00
1e-11
1e-10
1e-09
1e-08
1e-07
1e-06
1e-05
1e-04
1e-03
1e-02
1e-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but this also works:

```
import numpy as np

for x in [0] + list(10.0**np.arange(-6,-2)):
    print(x)
```

Or without numpy:

```
for x in [0] + [10**i for i in range(-6,-2)]:
    print(x)
```